# REACT array props inaccessible

Tags: reactjs, arrays, undefined

I'm new on React and got a problem with the props.

I got a props, name location, that is an array and I want to access to location.pictures[0]
location.pictures is an array who got 5 pictures.

But when I try, the console say :

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and how to create [mcve].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: thanks, ok i'm going to read that.